# JXBrowser multiple StartIPCTasks in OSGi application. How to reinitialize Browser properly?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, jxbrowser

I'm working on a JXBrowser plugin in an OSGi application for work, but when I update the plugin I get this error:

[JXBrowser multiple instance error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XtTe.png)

I can't find any information on the StartIPCTask, but I know it is run when a Browser is instantiated. I tried to specify BrowserContext with the same path always, but I get the same error. I also tried disposing of the browser object (and optionally running BrowserCore.shutdown()) when the app is updated but I get the same error or it all crashes.

Is there some special way to garbage collect browsers and ensure that the StartIPCTask is only implemented once?  Can I specify which one is undefined programmatically? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately I can't post all my code but the gist of the project is encapsulating JXBrowser in an app. So when the app is created it calls a `start` function, which contains:

```
try {
    browser = new Browser();
    browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
    browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
            Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
            JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
            window.asObject().setProperty("browser", browser);
        }
    });
} catch (IPCException exception) {
    System.out.println("Must restart to use browser");
    // This executes after a 1 minute delay (shown below)
}
```

Before the app is reinstalled for an update, the `shutdown()` method is called, which right now is just:

```
if (browser != null)
    browser.dispose();
```

According to the documentation, since I am on Mac OSX, Browsers and BrowserContexts must be manually disposed. But adding either function has no effect.

When the app is then reloaded, the start method is run again and the `browser` declaration line fails with the following error:

```
objc[71371]: Class StartIPCTask is implemented in both 
/path/to/karaf_data/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.2/data/Temp/libjxbrowser-common64-fb50af13-9fbf-4fe0-a9cf-0a1f9d1201a7.dylib (0x144e95610) 
and /path/to/karaf_data/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-55.0.2883.87.6.14.2/data/Temp/libjxbrowser-common64-29e240a5-75e5-4ece-9fe7-33dd8b3245cb.dylib (0x180db9610).
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

But there is no option to specify which is undefined. So instead, it remains frozen for ~1 minute, then the code continues with `browser` as null.

Should I be specifying a BrowserContext other than the BrowserContext.defaultContext()? How do I inform the BrowserCore to exit without exiting the parent application, and can I then create a new Browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this error because your OSGI application uses different ClassLoaders to load JNI library which is a part of JxBrowser. The libjxbrowser-common64...dylib is a singleton JNI library. If you try loading it with different ClassLoaders, the error mentioned above happens. This is a well known limitation based on JNI-OSGI partial incompatibility.
Also in MacOSX the Chromium process is run as a part of Java process and in the multiple JxBrowser instances configuration Chromium might have an unexpected behavior.
To resolve this issue I suggest that you run Chromium as an external process, e.g. using the -Djxbrowser.ipc.external=true VM parameter, and find the way to forbid OSGI environment using different ClassLoaders for JxBrowser library.